# SQL Server vs. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am confused about the database I should choose, since the application I am doing will store and handle large amounts of data, I think SQL Server will be better than MySQL. Any recommendations?

Comment: Please specify more detail about your use case. For storing big data you should go with NoSQL DB like Mongo DB or Cassandra DB etc. Please also specify the front end server you are using like with PHP it is preferable to use MySql, while with ASP.net it is preferable to use SQL Server

Comment: well, but if i have to choose between SQL Server and MySQL, which is better in my case, and what i meant with "Big Data" not the common used word about big data like the that in hadoop , i meant that the app will store too many rows in a single table. and i want to know if SQLserver is really much better than MySQL, or it doesn't at all. thanks in advance

Comment: Commercial ? Free? How BIG Data? What kind of application? Financial? Multimedia? Many programmers suggest PostgreSQL too

Comment: If you're asking this kind of question, then MySQL is probably what you should choose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both platforms SQL Server and MySQL can handle small and large software projects, so you should anticipate similar performance from both, provided the database designer and programmer are familiar with the right way to optimize queries and code.

Structured query language (SQL) is the language of relational databases. Several database platforms use SQL, but a slight variation on it—each tend to have a slightly different syntax. Microsoft SQL and MySQL are two of the most common database platforms on the web. Once you go with one, it can be very difficult to switch to the other. That’s because the database platform you choose will end up being the core of your dynamic content moving forward. It stores, secures, and retrieves all the data for your applications.

It’s an important decision to make, and will likely hinge on a few things. If you’re having a hard time deciding which one is right for your project, here’s a look at some similarities and differences between the two, SQL and MySQL.

**THE BASICS**

Whether you want to store, retrieve or edit your data—the way dynamic websites and applications perform nearly every request a user makes—SQL is the language of choice for relational databases. On the surface, both Microsoft and MySQL look similar:

- They both give you the ability to host several databases on one
  server.
- They use tables to store data.
- They have primary and foreign    key constraints.
- They use indexes to sort data and speed up performance, and they both support desktop and web applications.

SQL Server is slightly older than MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server was introduced in 1989 and MySQL was introduced in 1995 as an open-source project. Since both of them have been in production for years, they both have a firm foothold in the market. MySQL runs on either Windows or Linux, typically as a part of a LAMP environment. SQL Server runs on Windows, and is usually a part of a Windows environment.

Both platforms handle small and large software projects, so you should anticipate similar performance from both, provided the database designer and programmer are familiar with the right way to optimize queries and code.

**Microsoft SQL Server vs. MySQL: Similarities**

Both Microsoft and MySQL are relational database platforms, so they have several similarities. Most developers specialize in either one or the other, because although they appear similar, the way they work in the underlying architecture is very different. Here are some similarities, which make it somewhat easy for a database developer to work on both platforms efficiently, even if they specialize in only one.

**Scalability**: Both platforms allow you to scale as your business grows. You can use both for small projects, however should these projects take off to an enterprise-level, they can still support millions of transactions a day.
High-performance: A database is your application’s backbone. It stores your all of data, so you need a database that can return data in less than a second. Both platforms can handle this type of high-performance speed.

**Tables:** Both platforms use the standard relational database table model to store data in rows and columns.
Keys: Both platforms use primary and foreign keys to establish relationships between tables.

**Syntax:** Syntax between the two database platforms are similar, although there are some minor differences across different CRUD (create, read, update, delete) statements.

**Web-based popularity:** Aside from Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are the most common databases used for web applications. When you sign up for hosting, you typically get a choice between MySQL databases or SQL Server.
Drivers: You can find connection drivers for almost any popular language on the web, so you can easily connect to both platforms without writing complex code.

**MICROSOFT SQL SERVER VS. MYSQL: DIFFERENCES**

While the two platforms are similar in the interface and basic relational database standards, they are two very different programs and operate differently. Most of the differences are in the way they operate in the background, and these differences are not seen by the average user. As long as the database performs well, it can be used with your project. However, it’s still important to know these differences because they’ll play a huge role in your developer’s choice platform.

**Native compatibility:** You can use either database with both Windows and Linux projects, but MySQL works natively with PHP and MSSQL is mainly used with .NET. It makes integration simpler if you stick with MySQL for PHP and MSSQL for Windows projects.

**MyISAM and InnoDB:** Both of these engines are configurations for MySQL and allow the developer to perform very different design and programming. With MSSQL, you create a database and don’t specify different engines.

**Cost:** SQL Server is generally expensive to run, because you need licenses for the server running the software. MySQL is free and open-source, but you’ll pay for support if you need it.

**LINQ:** With MSSQL, you can set up your entity framework classes in .NET and get started with LINQ queries. With MySQL and .NET, you need to download third-party provider tools.

**IDE tools:** Both platforms have IDE tools, but you need the right tool with the right server. MSSQL uses Management Studio and MySQL has Enterprise Manager. These tools let you connect to the server and manage settings and configurations for security, architecture, and table design.

**WHICH ONE SHOULD YOU USE?**

The database you use usually depends on the hosting environment you choose. Linux hosting providers usually offer MySQL. Since MySQL is open-source and free, you can have as many databases as you need. You can have 10 of them to support 10 different projects if need be.

Because SQL Server costs money for licenses, Windows hosts will give you one MSSQL database and you must pay for additional ones. Overall, this makes SQL Server more costly than MySQL. However, SQL Server works natively with .NET applications, so it’s the choice for software that runs on a Windows server or desktop. The development tools are free, but the production environment is not free.

The best way to determine the right platform is to first post your project in the marketplace and discuss your requirements with a few developers. You will get different opinions and preferences based on the developer’s area of expertise, but most Windows developers work with MSSQL and Linux developers work with MySQL. You should decide which environment you want to target, and then you can get a clearer idea of which platform is right for you.

Source
[sql-vs-mysql-which-relational-database-is-right-for-you](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/data/sql-vs-mysql-which-relational-database-is-right-for-you/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both Mysql and mssql can handle big data. but mysql is better in this ways

1. security: if  You choose Mssql u'll host on windows server which is considered less secure.

NB: SQL Server 2017 available on Linux. but most hosting companys haven't updated it

2. Cost: hosting Companies will give little free database space on Mssql compared to mysql.

   example in godaddy MSSQL 1 database x 200MB(economyPlan) 2 x 200MB(deluxe) Unlimited x 200MB(ultimate).

MySQL databases 10 x 1 GB(economy) 25 x 1 GB(deluxe) Unlimited x 1 GB(ultimate).

Comment: 1. Nonsense. Windows is considered less secure by who? Linux admins? It's not less secure. Look at the data breaches of 2017-2018 and before even. I ran Windows Servers on a major backbone for several years with no firewall (not even the Windows firewall due to a multi-ip to same port bug) and never had a problem. Windows is not the security problem, Windows users (and 3rd party devs) are the problem. A half conscious admin can secure Windows. Good luck with the others, the best resources in the world can't secure all the hundreds of millions of breached records this year and last.

Comment: Indeed, that is nonsense. We had a security consultant last year come in with actual data breach statistics, corrupted data stats and performance stats. MySQL suffered the most data breaches of any RDB out there, even in 2020, the incidences of corruption and ACID fails was also high, and performance wise, still the all time loser. Oracle ensures this to sell Oracle RDBMS (Oracle has done very little to improve MySQL - like any good company, they aren't going to compete with themselves).

Answer (score -1):

If your not sure, then  you probably don't have alot of experience. I would suggest you start with MySQL assuming you have Linux available. It is much more forgiving and allows you to quickly re-start the database if you mess something up. SQL Server is almost impossible to stop and restart without rebooting the windows server, which is a long process and could bring your whole system down for 10 minutes or more. A Mysql restart in linux takes 2 seconds or less.

Sql Server is MUCH more expensive but it has many more tools and features.

If you are looking to use this as a backend to get more development work, SQL server DB's generally get more money, and it is used more in corporate world. Microsoft has extensive tools and addins with SQL server, much more than my sql.

It is interesting to note that SQL Server can connect to MySQl to allow you to write queries in SQL server that directly query Mysql (this is called a linked server) , but the reverse is not possible. So in the future, you could split up your databases. AS a general rule of thumb, if you have website traffic coming in AND backend processing, create multiple databases, even if they are on the same server, so you can move one of them off to another server when your the database gets busy.

Comment: SQL Server isn't difficult to stop and restart. You right click on the service, and choose restart. Not all versions of SQL Server are expensive. Express Edition, which supports db's up to 10GB, is free, even for commercial use.

Comment: user1751825 is correct, it is easy to restart SQL Server. However, actually installing SQL server and all its tools, PLUS installing SQL management studio can be a bear. You have to educate yourself on the tools you will need. If you plan on lots of users or web traffic, then express edition might limit you. Most of the detail information you need is available on youtube

Comment: @ClarkVera What you said is not any more true for MSSQL than it is for MySQL. That's assuming you're running MySQL on Windows (which works pretty well and has a nice installer). If you're running MySQL on Linux, then there is an even steeper learning curve as you sit there staring at a mysql prompt and wondering what now?

Comment: This answer is otherwise not true except for cost, especially the part about MSSQL being hard to restart. I would recommend the opposite of this answer. Go with MSSQL Express Edition until you outgrow it and then go with MySQL due to licensing costs. Both are good, but MSSQL license costs (and the licensing itself) is horrible once you have to start actually paying for it.